# Should "food" and "nutrition" be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, [food](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) is automatically changed to [nutrition](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition).

Is this policy correct?

Answer (score 2):

No, [food](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) is different from [nutrition](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition).

[nutrition](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) is specific

> Nutritional science investigates the metabolic and physiological responses of the body to diet.

—[Wikipedia – Nutrition](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutrition#section_1)

Example: *Does asparagus contain enough vitamins for a whole day?*

Whereas [food](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) is generic

> Food is any substance consumed to provide nutritional support for the body.

—[Wikipedia – Food](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food)

Example: *Do blue carrots exist?*

As such they should be used as appropriate and not synonyms: [nutrition](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) for questions about the nutritional properties, and [food](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) for more general questions about food.

Note: sometimes food is better tagged [natural-remedies](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-remedies) or [herbalism](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/herbalism)

Examples: *Does orange prevent flu?*; *Does chicory enhance your eyesight?*

Comment: Tentative +1 but I see this potentially result in a lot of re-tagging with unclear boundaries. Sometimes a general, non-specific tag is enough.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Agreed, maybe "[foodstuffs](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/foodstuff)" could be used to define the difference as it is a bit more specific?

Comment: @RobZ is foodstuff a common enough word? Should we replace food->foodstuff on future tags?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think both could co-exist. A question could be about food and nutrition (are carrots good for me?), or about food only (do blue carrots exist?), or nutrition only (do vitamins survive cooking?)

Comment: @Sklivvz - Not sure if it is or not, I tend to write with a slightly antiquated style but I have heard the term used before when people were talking about logistics so, maybe?

Comment: Blue carrots may not be edible, so i think [plants] and [biology] are better tags than [food]. For dishes, see [cooking.stackexchange.com](http://cooking.stackexchange.com).